# Listing ioctl calls from userspace to kernelspace

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ioctl

Might be my question sounds more naive.

But I wanted to know if it is possible to list the ioctl calls made from user space to kernel space in Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try `strace`? it list all syscalls.

Comment: But I have many userspace application running in userspace .. using strace I can only trace syscalls made by a particular application right ?

Comment: if you want system-wide, use `systemtap`, see `para-callgraph.stp` in example page/

Answer (score 8):

Use [LTTng](http://lttng.org/). This is a modern Linux kernel tracer (works in user land too) that installs in seconds (available as packages) if you're using Ubuntu, Fedora, Arch Linux, Debian or openSUSE. Otherwise, it's still easy [getting the tarballs](http://lttng.org/download) and following the install procedures.

### Tracing

You create a trace like this:

```
$ sudo lttng create mySession
Session mySession created.
Traces will be written in /home/user/lttng-traces/mySession-20120619-103600
$ sudo lttng enable-event -k -a --syscall
All kernel system calls are enabled in channel channel0
$ sudo lttng start
Tracing started for session mySession
```

Then do your normal stuff. All system calls, including `ioctl`, are recorded/captured by LTTng with interesting parameters. A trace is being written to the `/home/user/lttng-traces/mySession-20120619-103600` directory. When you're finished recording, do:

```
$ sudo lttng stop
Tracing stopped for session mySession
$ sudo lttng destroy
Session mySession destroyed at /home/ephipro
```

Although `destroy` doesn't sound good here, it does not actually *destroy* the trace files; it simply flushes everything and frees any link to the files.

`sudo` is needed everywhere since you are tracing kernel events. You don't want any user to see all the system calls and their parameters for obvious security reasons.

### Viewing the trace

Two main viewers are available now. **Babeltrace** will give you a text output of all captured events. You should be able to get it using `apt-get` (`babeltrace`), otherwise just get the [latest tarball](http://www.efficios.com/files/babeltrace/?C=M;O=D). Then just use `grep` to extract the `ioctl` calls from the huge dump Babeltrace outputs:

```
$ sudo babeltrace /home/user/lttng-traces/mySession-20120619-103600 | grep ioctl
[10:36:41.795425690] (+0.000001403) sys_ioctl: { 1 }, { fd = 18, cmd = 62981, arg = 0 }
[10:36:41.795435996] (+0.000000610) sys_ioctl: { 1 }, { fd = 18, cmd = 2148070920, arg = 139928632507464 }
[10:36:41.795573431] (+0.000008840) sys_ioctl: { 1 }, { fd = 18, cmd = 62982, arg = 4096 }
[10:36:41.795591089] (+0.000000854) sys_ioctl: { 1 }, { fd = 18, cmd = 62981, arg = 38520960 }
[10:36:41.795595956] (+0.000000434) sys_ioctl: { 1 }, { fd = 18, cmd = 2148070920, arg = 139928632507464 }
[10:36:41.796125261] (+0.000006110) sys_ioctl: { 1 }, { fd = 18, cmd = 62982, arg = 0 }
[10:36:41.796185722] (+0.000000947) sys_ioctl: { 1 }, { fd = 18, cmd = 62981, arg = 38530304 }
[10:36:41.796192688] (+0.000000628) sys_ioctl: { 1 }, { fd = 18, cmd = 2148070920, arg = 139928632507464 }
[10:36:41.797155511] (+0.000003280) sys_ioctl: { 0 }, { fd = 18, cmd = 62982, arg = 0 }
[10:36:41.797202362] (+0.000001995) sys_ioctl: { 0 }, { fd = 18, cmd = 62981, arg = 38529760 }
...
```

What you see here is at which time the event occured, the event name and all its parameters and values.

Eclipse also features a complete LTTng viewer within the Linux Tools plugins project. The easy steps are:

1. Go to [eclipse.org's download page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)
2. Into *Developer Builds* (until Eclipse Juno is released in a few days), get *Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers*
3. Extract it and start it

Starting from Eclipse Juno, Linux Tools is embedded into Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers.

You may then create a new **Tracing project** and import the trace. If you open the **Tracing** perspective, you will have access to useful views to visualize the events. Here's an example of the **Histogram** and **Events** views:

[image: Eclipse LTTng viewer]

Here I used the Events view to keep only `ioctl` calls and you can clearly see that the content and time stamps match the Babeltrace output.